# recursive menu item with default template and itemTemplate

Tags: wpf, datatemplate, menuitem, controltemplate

I have a WPF Control template for the `MenuItem` type:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
    <Setter Property="Background"
            Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="Cursor"
            Value="Hand" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
                <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ContentControl Content="{TemplateBinding Header}"
                                        Margin="5"
                                        Grid.Column="1" />
                        <Path Grid.Column="2"
                                x:Name="Indicator"
                                Data="M1,1 L1,9 9,5Z"
                                Fill="{StaticResource GlyphBrush}"
                                Margin="4"
                                Visibility="Hidden"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                        <Popup Name="PART_Popup"
                                Placement="Right"
                                IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsSubmenuOpen}"
                                AllowsTransparency="True"
                                Grid.Column="0"
                                Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                                HorizontalOffset="3"
                                VerticalOffset="-1">
                            <Border Background="Transparent">
                                <ContentControl Style="{StaticResource PopupContentStyle}">
                                    <ItemsPresenter/>
                                </ContentControl>
                            </Border>
                        </Popup>
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsChecked"
                                Value="false">
                        <Setter Property="Background"
                                Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems"
                                Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Indicator"
                                Property="Visibility"
                                Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Opacity"
                                Value="{StaticResource DisabledTransparency}" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                    Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background"
                    Value="{StaticResource ButtonHoverBackgroundBrush}" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

If I do now add items to a `MenuItem` the template works flawless. But if I try to add items to a bound `ObservableCollection` I run into problems as my `ControlTemplate` does not use the `ItemTemplate` of the original `MenuItem` anywhere.

This usage causes problems:

```
<MenuItem Header="{userInterface:Translation Language}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}">
    <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ChangeLanguageCommand}"
                      CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}"
                      Header="{Binding}" />
            </DataTemplate>
    </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
</MenuItem>
```

The `MenuItem` does not use the `Template` I specified above, instead it does again take my default template.

I tried changing the `ItemsPresenter` of my global template to a `ItemsControl` but it did change nothing.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this fixed by changing the `ItemTemplate` to a `ItemContainerStyle`:
this is the result:

```
    <MenuItem Header="{userInterface:Translation Language}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}">
        <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="MenuItem"
                    BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type MenuItem}}">
                <Setter Property="Header"
                        Value="{Binding Name}" />
                <Setter Property="Command"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ChangeLanguageCommand}" />
                <Setter Property="CommandParameter"
                        Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=DataContext}" />
                <Setter Property="IsChecked"
                        Value="{Binding IsSelected}">
                </Setter>
            </Style>
        </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    </MenuItem>
```

Problem of the initial `ItemTemplate` is that the `MenuItem` internal uses a `MenuItem` as item container template. which resulted in a `MenuItem` inside a `MenuItem` where the `Command` and the `CommandProperty` where on the inner `MenuItem` while the Style was on the outer `MenuItem`. Which was causing Problems with my `Command` because the outer `MenuItem` already consumes the `Click`.

Now using the `ItemContainerStyle` the setters get applied to the correct `MenuItem` while using the `BasedOn` property takes all Setters of the Global `MenuItem` style.

Answer (score 1):

Console,

1. **Name your style** :

```
<Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
```

2. And every time you intend to use it, use the **named resource** :

```
 <MenuItem Header="Hello" 
           ItemsSource="{Binding AvailableLanguages}"
           Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}">
   <MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <MenuItem Style="{DynamicResource MenuItemStyle1}" 
                 Command="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=DataContext.ChangeLanguageCommand}"
                 CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Header}">
         <MenuItem.Header>
           <TextBlock Text="Hello" />
         </MenuItem.Header>
       </MenuItem>
     </DataTemplate>
   </MenuItem.ItemTemplate>
```

Regards

Comment: I tried this out but it shows no Effekt, the gloabal MenuItem Template is still not consuming the item template anywhere.

Comment: Of course like in the above post, you assign the style to BOTH menus, do you ? I just posted my project. I got it working(even if it is really ugly).  http://1drv.ms/1GWDPUm