# WPF MenuItem not filling available ContextMenu space

Tags: c#, wpf, user-interface, mahapps.metro

I'm having a weird problem with a simple ContextMenu using MahApps.Metro without any additional styling. When moving the cursor on top of the text or slightly around it, there is no problem. But when moving it further away, still inside the ContextMenu bounds, the Cursor is no longer on top of the MenuItem. Clicking now also doesn't result in any action at all besides closing the ContextMenu.

[image] 
[image]

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextItems}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why doesn't the MenuItem use the available space?

Comment: I've just found this problem for myself. To my eye, for some reason, it looks like it's actually adding two menu items, one as a the content to the other. That's why they're centered (rather than the default left justified), larger and the pressing isn't being processed right - because it's firing the event on the strange empty one that contains the actual item. It's quite frustrating. Not found a solution yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your `ContextItems` holds a collection with viewmodels then I think this could help you (not tested):

```
<ContextMenu ItemsSource="{Binding ContextItems}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Text}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}" />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```

Command and Text should be the properties on the viewmodel object.

Comment: Good explanation for related question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33677759/2346621

Answer (score 2):

I havent used MahApps.Metro . Though you can override the template like this

```
                <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                      <MenuItem Header="{Binding Text}" Command="{Binding Command}"/>
                        <MenuItem.Template>
                            <ControlTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Header,RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                            </ControlTemplate>
                        </MenuItem.Template>
                        </MenuItem>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: yeah, the border around the menuitems disappeared - is there also a way to stretch the item to fit in the normal sized context menu? even if not, thx for the fast reply!

Comment: just found a problem: now only the text is clickable, all whitespace doesn't trigegr the command....

Comment: Try to Wrap ContentPresenter in Grid like <Grid><ContentPresenter....../></Grid> .